# React-native: MainApplication.java:3: error: package android.app does not exist

Tags: java, android, react-native

I updated jdk from 8 to 11, and now I can no longer launch android with react-native. Also I upgraded compileSdkVersion from 29 to 31.

When I try launching it, I get these errors:

> /path_to_main_application/MainApplication.java:3: error: package android.app does not exist
> import android.app.Application;
> ^
> /path_to_main_application/MainApplication.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
> public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
> ^
> symbol: class Application
> /path_to_main_activity/MainActivity.java:3: error: package android.os does not exist
> import android.os.Bundle; // here
> ^
> /path_to_main_activity/MainActivity.java:10: error: cannot access ViewGroup
> public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
> ^
> class file for android.view.ViewGroup not found

I also had to remove my old android studio and download a new one, as the old one did not accept jdk 11 for some reason. So now Im on a brand new android studio (Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1) with jdk 11 and cannot run android anymore.

My react-native version is: 0.59.10